# Where can I find is $.post()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, postback

I want to post back a page with Javascript in asp.net mvc3 razor, I so I search around and I see people using `$.post(blabla)`, but I don't know where this `post` function is?

Could anyone explain to me how to call this `post` function?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities what `$.post` could be. The well-known jQuery library offers this function for example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/, where it is a wrapper for their full-fledged [`$.ajax` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: If I type `$.` the javascript intellisense dropdown menu doesn't provide an option for `post`? I have jQuery. What am I missing?

Comment: Here: http://blog.craigtp.co.uk/post/Javascript-jQuery-Intellisense-in-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx. You shouldn't rely on intellisense to know what methods and variables your codebase has.

Comment: How intelligent is your intellisense? Since the post method is included since version 1.0, it should work (if properly configured).

Answer (score 1):

This is part of jQuery and, like `$.get()`, one of the shorthands to [the ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :

See [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Note that it's impossible to be 100% sure : you can very well define a function like this without jQuery :

```
var $ = {
   post: function(){...}
};
```

The main way to be sure is to look for an import in the head of the HTML file (though it's possible to have it named differently or dynamically loaded), something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into http://jquery.com. Its a function from that library.

Answer (score 1):

That's a function in jQuery to make an AJAX call, you won't use that to post back a page.

Use the `submit` function on the form that you want to post back. Example:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Comment: Ah okay. But actionlink's don't require a form, why does Javascript need them?

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: An actionlink doesn't make a post, it makes a get.